# Qt How to get sender of sender signal or how to know loadStarted url of QWebEngineView?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qwebengineview, qwebenginepage

QWebEngineView has signal void loadStarted(). It emits this signal when it received from QWebEnginePage. QWebEnginePage overrides this function from QWebEnginePagePrivate, where it is void loadStarted(const QUrl &provisionalUrl, bool isErrorPage = false), but in QWebEnginePage class argument provisionalUrl marked as Q_UNUSED(), but I want to know its value. How can I do it?

Comment: Or How via QWebEngineView get parameters of form's method  "POST" or "GET" and hyperlink's url clicked on displayed web page?

Comment: What about the result of calling QWebEnginePage::url(), does that not tell you which URL/page has been loaded/viewed? Also take a look at QWebEnginePage::requestedUrl() - The URL requested to loaded by the frame currently viewed. The URL may differ from the one returned by url() if a DNS resolution or a redirection occurs.

Comment: I tried QWebEnginePage::requestedUrl() - it returns address of already loaded page. I need to intercept on page buttons presses and links clicking.  To know what link was clicked, generate new web-page and navigate user on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to intercept navigation requests and filter them by navigation type, the best you can do is to override QWebEnginePage::acceptNavigationRequest() virtual function.

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#acceptNavigationRequest

```
class NavigationRequestOverride : public QWebEnginePage
{
public:
    NavigationRequestOverride(QObject* parent) : QWebEnginePage(parent) {}
protected:
    virtual bool acceptNavigationRequest(const QUrl &url, NavigationType type, bool isMainFrame)
    {
       // Here goes your logic
    }
};
```